# Perl param() receiving from its own print HTML

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi

I have a Perl script that reads in data from a database and prints out the result in HTML forms/tables. The form of each book also contains a submit button.

I want Perl to create a text file (or read into one already created) and print the title of the book that was inside the form submitted. But I can't seem to get `param()` to catch the submit action!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;      # Allow for warnings to be sent if error's occur
use CGI;           # Include CGI.pm module
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;    # Database data will come from mysql

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:name?book_store', 'name', 'password')
    or die("Could not make connection to database: $DBI::errstr");  # connect to the database with address and pass or return error

my $q = new CGI;                     # CGI object for basic stuff
my $ip = $q->remote_host();          # Get the user's ip
my $term = $q->param('searchterm');  # Set the search char to $term
$term =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;                # set all characters to lowercase for convenience of search

my $sql = '
  SELECT *
  FROM Books
  WHERE Title LIKE ?
    OR Description LIKE ?
    OR Author LIKE ?
';                    # Set the query string to search the database

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);    # Prepare to connect to the database

$sth->execute("%$term%", "%$term%", "%$term%")
    or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  # Connect to the database or return an error

print $q->header;
print "<html>";
print "<body>";

print " <form name='book' action='bookcart.php' method=post> ";  # Open a form for submitting the result of book selection

print "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"> ";

my $title  = $data[0];
my $desc   = $data[1];
my $author = $data[2];
my $pub    = $data[3];
my $isbn   = $data[4];
my $photo  = $data[5];

print "<tr> <td width=50%>Title: $title</td> <td width=50% rowspan=5><img src=$photo height=300px></td></tr><tr><td>Discreption Tags: $desc</td></tr><tr><td>Publication Date: $pub</td></tr><tr><td>Author: $author</td></tr><tr><td>ISBN: $isbn</td> </tr></table> <br>";

print "Add this to shopping cart:<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'>";

if ($q->param('submit')) {
    open(FILE, ">>'$ip'.txt");
    print FILE "$title\n";
    close(FILE);
}

print "</form>";    # Close the form for submitting to shopping cart
```

Comment: In what context do you run this script? Is it a CGI script run by a webserver? what is `bookcart.php`? What is `$data`? Why do you mix html/form creation with parameter evaluation? What do you expect the file name of your output file to look like?

Comment: the output is the user's ip address whose accesing the page, its html so I can format the output of the database, the script is to pull data from a database of books after a search term was submitted from another html page, $data is a place holder for moving the data from the database draw to the html table.

Comment: Well, I guess you will be surprised to see the real output filename. I guess you didn't answer the most important question: Why do you mix html/form creation with parameter evaluation?

Comment: Then why not try to make baby steps and learn one thing at a time? Create a html file with a form, submit the form to a little script and play with that.

Comment: Cause its due in 2 and a half hours... I've been working on this since friday... STRAIGHT!

Answer (score 3):

- You haven't used `use strict`, to force you to declare all your variables. This is a *bad idea*
- You have used `remote_host`, which is the *name* of the client host system. Your server may not be able to resolve this value, in which case it will remain unset. If you want the IP address, use `remote_addr`
- You have prepared and executed your SQL statement but have fetched no data from the query. You appear to expect the results to be in the array `@data`, but you haven't declared this array. You would have been told about this had you had `use strict` in effect
- You have used the string `'$ip'.txt` for your file names so, if you were correctly using the IP address in stead of the host name, your files would look like `'92.17.182.165'.txt`. Do you really want the single quotes in there?
- You don't check the status of your `open` call, so you have no idea whether the open succeeded, or the reason why it may have failed

I doubt if you have really spent the last 48 hours coding this. I think it is much more likely that you are throwing something together in a rush at the last minute, and using Stack Overflow to help you out of the hole you have dug for yourself.

Before asking for the aid of others you should at least use minimal good-practice coding methods such as applying `use strict`. You should also try your best to debug your code: it would have taken very little to find that `$ip` has the wrong value and `@data` is empty.

Comment: You are being criticized because you appear to have made very little effort to help yourself, and are expecting others to do things for you. That isn't asking for help, it's passing the buck.

Answer (score 1):

**Use** `strict` and `warnings`. You want to use `strict` for many reasons. A decent article on this is over at perlmonks, you can begin with this. [Using strict and warnings](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=111088)

You don't necessarily need the following line, you are using DBI and can access mysql strictly with DBI.

```
use DBD::mysql;
```

Many of options are available with `CGI`, I would recommend reading the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) on this also based on user preferences and desired wants and needs.

I would not use the following:

```
my $q = new CGI;

# I would use as so..
my $q = CGI->new;
```

Use `remote_addr` instead of remote_host to retrieve your ip address.

The following line you are converting all uppercase to lowercase, unless it's a need to specifically read from your database with all lowercase, I find this useless.

```
$term =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
```

Next your $sql line, again user preference, but I would look into `sprintf` or using it directly inside your calls. Also you are trying to read an array of data that does not exist, where is the call to get back your data? I recommend reading the documentation for `DBI` also, many methods of returning your data. So you want your data back using an array for example...

Here is an untested example and hint to help get you started.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use CGI qw( :standard );
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser ); # Track your syntax errors
use DBI;

# Get IP Address
my $ip = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};

# Get your query from param, 
# I would also parse your data here
my $term = param('searchterm') || undef;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:db:host', 'user', 'pass', 
                       {RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sql = sprintf ('SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE %s 
                    OR Description LIKE %s', $term, $term);

my $sth = $dbh->selectall_arrayref( $sql );

# Retrieve your result data from array ref and turn into 
# a hash that has title for the key and a array ref to the data.
my %rows = ();
for my $i ( 0..$#{$sth} ) {
  my ($title, $desc, $author, $pub, $isbn, $pic) = @{$sth->[$i]};
  $rows{$title} = [ $desc, $author, $pub, $isbn, $pic ];  
}

# Storing your table/column names 
# in an array for mapping later.
my @cols;
$cols[0] = Tr(th('Title'), th('Desc'), th('Author'), 
              th('Published'), th('ISBN'), th('Photo'));

foreach (keys %rows) {
   push @cols, Tr( td($_), 
                   td($rows{$_}->[0]),
                   td($rows{$_}->[1]),
                   td($rows{$_}->[2]),
                   td($rows{$_}->[3]),
                   td(img({-src => $rows{$_}->[4]}));
}

print header,
      start_html(-title => 'Example'),
      start_form(-method => 'POST', -action => 'bookcart.php'), "\n",
      table( {-border => undef, -width => '100%'}, @cols ),
      submit(-name => 'Submit', -value => 'Add Entry'),
      end_form,
      end_html;

# Do something with if submit is clicked..
if ( param('Submit') ) {

   ......

}
```

Comment: Apart from being superfluous, the use of tr// is also definitely the wrong way to upper-case a string since it only does its magic in the ASCII-range.

Answer (score -2):

This assumes that you're using the OO approach to CGI.pm, and that $q is the relevant object.  This should work, assuming that you have `$q = new CGI` somewhere in your script.

Can you post the rest of the script?

I've created a mockup to test this, and it works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

my $q = new CGI;

print $q->header;
print "<form><input type=submit name=submit value='add'></form>\n";

if ($q->param('submit')) {
    print "submit is \"" . $q->param('submit') . "\"\n";
}
```

After the submit button is clicked, the page displays that `submit is "add"` which means the evaluation is going as planned.

I guess what you need to do is make sure that $q is your CGI object, and move forward from there.

Comment: yea $q is the object and id do have use CGI up there too............... also I don't think your solution worked... it didn't create a new textfile in my winSCP folder

Comment: Likely because my solution doesn't create text files in WinSCP folders.  It could also be a permissions issue, the script doesn't have permissions to create files in the current working directory.  Try adding an `||` or `or` to your open call, like this:

`open (FILE, ">>'$ip'.txt") || print "<!-- Cannot open output file: $! -->\n";`

This will put an HTML comment in the resulting HTML page listing the error if it's unable to create the page.

Comment: not likely, all the permissions are set for reading writing and arithmetic. plus adding an error statement is just redundant.... I already know that it isn't opening and output file...

Comment: @DrewButler The error handling is *not* irrelevant: `$!` contains a reason for the error, E.g. no such path, no permissions, etc. Also, your script might run as a different user.